# How to add comments in PHP Eclipse?

Tags: php, eclipse

How can I add comments in PHP eclipse? I'm trying by selecting few lines of code, then right click, On menu, "Source"  and then I have tried all these options there "general element comment", "toggle comment", "Add block comment". None of them works. 
PS. I just downloaded latest eclipse PHP version.

Comment: It's a bug, that will be fixed in future releases. Hotfix is in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try Ctrl+Shift+/

The question is similair to [How to comment a block in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001586/how-to-comment-a-block-in-eclipse)

Comment: It is strange, but neither Ctrl-Shift-/ nor Ctrl-/, both don't work in my Eclipse anymore. Although they did before some update.

Comment: Hmm... So try to do this world better and send bugreport to Eclipse developers ;)

Comment: It seems somebody already did that. Here is the solution: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&goto=660274&S=89c1a463415c57c8bf9e4146b335f9e1 Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just try adding `/**` + enter? It will produce something like

```
/**
 * Comment here
 */
```

Remember to follow the doc order

```
/**
 * Description
 * @param argument/parameter
 * @return
 */
```

Comment: Im trying to comment some already existing blocks, and i cant do that this way. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @sabba, it's a bug in latest ecl

Answer (score 0):

It`s a [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=338291) in latest PHP eclipse. Fix is [here](http://sourceforge.jp/projects/pdt-tools/releases/51060).

Answer (score 0):

I was using single line comments on my eclipse php project. When i uploaded it to server ,some obfuscation has been applied automatically.Hence all the line breaks are removed and it treating the whole program as a single line. so i am getting an END OF STATEMENT error on server.So its better to use /*--*/ instead of //---- while commenting.