# In eclipse how can I uncomment blocks?

Tags: eclipse

I use a custom format and when ever I use it it makes every `/* */` comment into

```
/*
* code
* code
* code
* code
* code
*/
```

Is there a short key to uncomment this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to comment a block in Eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001586/how-to-comment-a-block-in-eclipse)

Comment: I tried that it only erase /**/ not the * inside (before the code lines)

Comment: You don't need the extra `*`s for each line. All you need are the beginning and end `/* code */`. Then just remove them when you need

Comment: the extra * are automatically added by eclipse using crtl+shift+f

Answer (score 0):

This formatting is the default behavior in Eclipse. My advice is to distinguish comments from disabling code.

**Comments**:
Use the block comment `/* ... */` only for real comments, or to insert comments within a single line of code, for example `anObject.aMethod(/* what means true here */ true);`.

**Disable code**:
Comment/Uncomment code always with `//` (Ctrl-7)`, in my experience this works perfectly. Then you can also uncomment single lines of the block.